# Unable to change Android bottom navigation bar background color

Tags: android, kotlin

Consider:

[image]

How I can change the 'Home' icon background ripple color or remove it?

`app:itemRippleColor="@color/primary"` is not working.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
</selector>
```

Its work for me.
I tried it with SDK > 19.